# Is there a way to get system time/date inside of a yew app?

Tags: rust, yew

Normally in a rust app, I'd get system time with `std::time::SystemTime::now()`, but that doesn't seem to work in a yew app. Instead the component I'm trying to read the system time from just silently (from the server logs) fails and in the web console I get `panicked at 'time not implemented on this platform'`.

Which makes sense, the client app can't just grab system time from the OS willy-nilly for security reasons. But does yew provide a way to get this from the browser?

Comment: Can't you just use [Javascript bindings](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/js_sys/struct.Date.html)?

Answer (score 1):

https://crates.io/crates/instant looks like it might do the job. But while it defines fn like now() I don't think that it will make crates that rely on std::time to work :-(

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the [chrono](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/) crate for this

```
info!("Time now is {}", chrono::Local::now());
```

And you can do all sorts of cool stuff with it! For example, if you have a `NaiveDateTime` in UTC you can convert it into the local user time like this:

```
use chrono::{Local, NaiveDateTime};

pub fn format_date(date: &NaiveDateTime) -> String {
    Local::from_utc_datetime(&Local, date).format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").to_string()
}
```

With formatting applied it will look like `2023-08-30 02:47:57`